# Finding a specific row in a PropelCollection

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I have two tables.  One for orders, and for their prefs.  The tables look like this:

*Order*:

```
+----------+---------------+------------+
| orderID  |  orderNumber  |  clientID  |
+----------+---------------+------------+
|    1     |    abc123     |     2      |
|    2     |    orderX     |     7      |
|    3     |    Joe9       |     2      |
|    4     |    Order4     |     2      |
+----------+---------------+------------+
```

*OrderPref*

```
+----------+----------+-------------+
| orderID  |  prefID  |  prefValue  |
+----------+----------+-------------+
|    1     |    1     |    $100     |
|    1     |    2     |    123      |
|    1     |    3     |    $35      |
|    2     |    1     |    $600     |
|    2     |    2     |    876      |
|    2     |    3     |    $44      |
+----------+----------+-------------+
```

What I want to is for each order, get the `prefValue` for a specific `prefID`.  Currently, this is what I am doing:

```
$orders = OrdersQuery::create()->filterByClientID(2)->find();

foreach($orders as $o){
    $prefs = $o->getOrderPrefs();

    foreach($prefs as $p){
        if($p->getPrefID() === 2){
            echo $p->getPrefValue();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but there needs to be a better way to get the one row I want for each order without looping through all the prefs.

I know this doesn't work, but is there something like this?

```
$orders = OrdersQuery::create()->filterByClientID(2)->find();

foreach($orders as $o){
    // This obviously doesn't work, so is there a short way to do this?
    echo $o->getOrderPrefs()->filterByPrefID(2)->getPrefValue();
}
```

I was reading the docs and found a [`->search()`](http://api.propelorm.org/1.6.0/runtime/propel-runtime-collection/PropelCollection.html#methodsearch) method, but I don't know how to use it.

```
$orders = OrdersQuery::create()->filterByClientID(2)->find();

foreach($orders as $o){
    // How can I search for the row with the prefID I want?
    echo $o->getOrderPrefs()->search()->getPrefValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at some old Propel stuff I've written, I'm guessing something like:

```
$prefValue = OrdersQuery::create()->
    joinOrderPref()->
    where('OrderPref.prefID = ?', $prefId)->
    filterByClientID($clientId)->
    select('OrderPref.prefValue')->
    find()
;
```

The issue is that you need to get a specific column ([reference](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#getting-columns-instead-of-objects)).

For these chainable queries, my view is that an auto-completing editor is pretty much mandatory - remembering the syntax is nigh-on impossible without it.

Comment: Problem is, this will return me `Orders`, each with a `getOrderPrefs` method; and now we're back at the original issue.  How can I get the `prefValue`s from this query?

Comment: So, the best way is to pre-select the column(s) I want to use?

Comment: That's certainly one way to do it. Alternatively, you could approach it from the perspective of the other table, and return a `OrderPref` object, from which `prefValue` can be read trivially.

Comment: Oh yeah!  I was thinking in the perspective of the `Order` table the whole time!

Comment: Seems like all solutions are doing too much work. It can all be done in one query, without the subqueries:
$prefValues = OrdersQuery::create()
        ->filterByClientId(2)
        ->joinOrderPrefs()
        ->withColumn('OrderPref.PrefValue', 'theValue')    /* gets that additional column from joined table and give 'theValue' alias to it */
        ->select('theValue')
        ->find();
The ->select() part is only the way to not get the fully bloated/hydrated object, but actually only an array with the prefValue data you need.

Comment: ^ @userfuser, can you put that in another answer? Large blocks of code don't work so well as comments `;-)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$prefValues = OrdersQuery::create()
        ->filterByClientId(2)
        ->joinOrderPref()
        ->withColumn('OrderPref.PrefValue', 'theValue')    
        // row above fetches ONLY the needed column from joined table and 
        // gives 'theValue' alias to it
        ->select('theValue')
        ->find();
```

With this you don't need to do any foreaches in PHP or do it in two steps.
About the `->select()` part - it's there only to not get the fully bloated/hydrated object, but actually only an array (PropelArrayCollection to be precise) with the prefValue data you need.

I didn't test this live though, some syntax issues may arise.